ERROR: Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-next ". Cannot find bounds of current function
I am trying to debug in VSCode using GDB. I am getting these errors when trying to step over a function.
Unable to step next. Operation failed with error code 0x80004004.

ERROR: Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-next ". Cannot find bounds of current function

what could I do to try fix this issue?
My gdb location is:
"MIMode": "gdb",
"miDebuggerPath": "${env:GCC11_HOME}/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe",

Let's see if the problem is in VS Code or lower. Run gdb <name of program> directly from the command line in the VS Code project's working directory, step until you either reach the end of the program or can't step as above and edit the question to add the results.

@user4581301 I opened the program in gdb, tried "step" received "the program is not being run", so I ran it, and got "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error".

Interesting. I think we need to see the compiler command line because either you're not building an executable or the compiler's building for the wrong platform.

This means you've ended up in a region of code with no line table information (what GDB uses for stepping) but also absolutely no symbol information, so GDB can't figure out the bounds of the current function.  I don't know how VS Code labels the actions, but from the GDB CLI I'd usually try finish (maybe called "step out"?).  Or you could manually look at the stack and place a breakpoint in the further up the stack and continue to that point.
